# Как восстановить basename в CentOs 6.6

Tags: centos

Так получилось, что из под рута удалил basename промахнувшись по бекспейсу. Буду рад, если кто подскажет как восстановить basename, либо откуда скачать и установить.

UPD:

```
yum reinstall coreutils
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это `coreutils`.
Скачайте и переустановите его

Вот здесь, например, можно скачать этот пакет:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/os/x86_64/Packages/

Переустановить rpm-пакет:

```
rpm -iv --replacepkgs filename.rpm
```

Comment: Благодарю за исправление глупости

Comment: @GlebVoronov: Рад помочь!